# TypeError: debounceTime is not a function

Tags: angular, rxjs

i'm trying to use rxjs for input autocomplete purpose but i keeping getting these error TypeError: terms.debounceTime is not a function
even i'm setting these import 'rxjs/operators/debounceTime';

the function where i call that is :

```js
    search(terms: Observable<string>) {
     return terms.debounceTime(400) 
     .distinctUntilChanged() 
     .switchMap(term => this.getActivities(term));
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I dont get rxjs 6 with angular 6 with interval, switchMap, and map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200859/i-dont-get-rxjs-6-with-angular-6-with-interval-switchmap-and-map)

Answer (score 7):

these working for me :

```js
search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.pipe(
      debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => this.getActivities(term))
    );
  }
```

it is about to pipe all !

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
```

or

```
import { debounceTime, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below way's

- import Subject

  `import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'`
- Declare it

  `private subject = new Subject<string>()`
- Then use it as

  ```
  search(terms: Observable<string>) {
   return  this.subject.debounceTime(400).distinctUntilChanged() 
       .switchMap(term => this.getActivities(term));
  }
  ```